# Cómo calcular la cantidad de parejas de elementos repetidos en una matrix Nx2 (python)?

Tags: python

Buenas tardes,

tengo una matrix Nx2 de la forma

> a_1,b_1
>   a_2,b_2,
>   ...
>   a_N,b_N

y me gustaría **calcular** para *cada pareja (a_i,b_i)* cuantas veces aparece repetida en la matriz y *almacenarlo en un vector*. De momento lo hago usando este código:

```
wij = [0]*len(matriz)
for i in range(0,len(matriz)):
    ai = matriz[i][0]
    bi = matriz[i][1]
    for k in range(0,len(matriz)):
        if(matriz[k][0]==ai and matriz[k][1]==bi):
            wij[i]+=1
```

Sin embargo este código no es óptimo, ya que recorro varias veces la misma *pareja (ai,bi)*. Lo óptimo creo que sería hacer primero una matriz la cual sólo contuviera las parejas de elementos únicas, y a partir de allí hacer el bucle.

Espero que poodáis ayudarme,

Un saludo

Comment: ¿La matriz es una lista de listas de 2 elementos? Si es así, ¿cómo accedes usando los índices separados por coma [i,0]? ¿No te da error?

Comment: Tienes razón, en realidad accedo usando [i][0], un fallo al copiar el código. Ahora lo arreglo, gracias ;)

Comment: alexm ¿que tipo de datos contiene tu matriz? ¿Son enteros, floats, str, etc o es mixta?

Comment: La matriz tiene sólo enteros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si la matriz es una lista de tuplas de 2 elementos, la manera más rápida de hacerlo es usando la función `Counter()` del módulo `collections`

```
import collections

cuenta_parejas = collections.Counter(matriz)
```

De esta manera, `cuenta_parejas` obtendría como resultado un objeto tipo `Counter` que se puede manejar como un diccionario donde las claves son las tuplas de 2 elementos de la matriz y el valor de cada clave es el número de veces que aparece.
La condición para poder usar esta función es que los objetos a contar en la lista tienen que poder ser *hasheables*, es decir, que no pueden ser mutables. Por eso el tener que usar tuplas como las filas de la matriz.

Por ejemplo:

```
m = [(1,2), (1,6), (1,2), (1,6), (8,9)]
cuenta_parejas = collections.Counter(m)
```

Daría como resultado

> `Counter({(1, 2): 2, (1, 6): 2, (8, 9): 1})`

Y la manera de obtener el número de veces que aparece una pareja o fila de en la matriz sería usando la tupla como clave de acceso:

```
cuenta_parejas[(1,2)] == 2
```

Tienes que tener en cuenta que si dos tuplas tienen los mismos elementos pero en orden inverso, las considera como distintas.
No sé si esto es exactamente lo que quieres

Comment: Es justamente lo que buscaba! Muchas gracias Carlos

Comment: Genial @alexm. Ésta la la forma más rápida que conozco. Pero de todas formas echa un vistazo a la otra solución de César porque además ha puesto la manera manual de resolver el problema con un bucle y seguro que aprendes también mucho de cómo se hacen este tipo de cosas manualmente.

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez puedas usar [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> matriz = [(1,True), (3,'k'), (10,2), (5,6), (1,True), (3,'k')]
>>> counter = Counter(matriz)
>>> counter
Counter({(3, 'k'): 2, (1, True): 2, (5, 6): 1, (10, 2): 1})
>>> counter[(3,'k')]
2
```

Las llaves son:

```
>>> counter.keys()
[(5, 6), (3, 'k'), (1, True), (10, 2)]
```

---

Si te interesa más el tema de los algoritmos, puedes hacer algo parecido usando tu propio diccionario:

```
>>> counter = {}
>>> for item in matriz:
...   if item not in counter:
...     counter[item] = 0
...   counter[item] += 1
... 
>>> counter
{(5, 6): 1, (3, 'k'): 2, (1, True): 2, (10, 2): 1}
>>> counter.keys()
[(5, 6), (3, 'k'), (1, True), (10, 2)]
>>> counter[(3, 'k')]
2
```

Lo anterior reduce la complejidad de tu algoritmo.

Comment: Bien puesta la forma manual de hacerlo @César. También opino que hacía falta informar al OP de ello.

Comment: @FJSevilla me enseñó en estos casos que si usas `defaultdict` es más sencillo, ya que no hace falta la comparación que comprueba si la clave existe. `counter = collections.defaultdict(int)`. Así `counter` es un diccionario donde las claves que metas parten de estar incializadas a `0`,  pudiendo eliminar el `if` del bucle.

Comment: Claro, pero eso tambien requeriría depender de la librería `collections`. Mi intención es mostrar el algoritmo sin ayuda de otras librerías.

Comment: Perfecto entonces. :)

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez dale ;)

Comment: Un momento, ¿y si usas el método `get()`? Quedaría así: `counter[item] = counter.get(item, 0) + 1` Así podrías quitar el `if` y no usar librerías. ¿Valdría?